# Vector multiplication faster if factor is not 1

Tags: r, performance, loops, random, time

I'm currently facing a problem for which I don't have any explanation.
Basically in a loop I'm multiplying a vector of 100 random points with a number. Like this:

```
for(i in 1:10000) {
  xs <- runif(100,0,1)
  ys <- runif(100,0,1)
  data <- factor*cbind(xs,ys)
  #do something with the data
}
```

If I set for example `factor <- 3` it works fine and after some time I have my result. But if factor is set to 1 (as parameter of a function) it takes forever. Is there any logical reason for this behavior?
Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems no problem as `factor <- 1`, by maybe caused by the steps when you don something with the data

Comment: It has to do something with multiplying by $1$. If I have `factor <- 1/2 * 2` it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @ThomasIscoding said, it must be something about what you do next in that `for loop` because there is no significant difference in calling that piece of code with either `factor = 1`, `factor = 1 / 2 * 2` or `factor = 3`:

```r
library(microbenchmark)

fn <- function(factor = 1) {
  for (i in 1:10000) {
    xs <- runif(100, 0, 1)
    ys <- runif(100, 0, 1)
    data <- factor * cbind(xs, ys)
    #do something with the data
  }

  return(data)
}

microbenchmark(fn(1),
               fn(1 / 2 * 2),
               fn(3),
               times = 10L)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#>        fn(1) 102.8349 108.2655 109.9209 108.6099 111.8287 122.4011    10   a
#>  fn(1/2 * 2) 101.8430 103.7025 112.1260 107.5010 111.9726 150.9856    10   a
#>        fn(3) 102.3946 105.0698 109.6703 107.7922 114.4457 119.2038    10   a
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Okay, I don't understand.. but thank you anyways!

Comment: We could help you further if you would share the complete code, i.e., that part of  `#do something with the data`.